# Is there a better way to hardcode shell script rather than a mix of cat and redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, hardcode

I wanted to make a hardcoded script automatically run as root and I came across this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat >/tmp/convert.sh <<EOF

some script here

EOF
chmod +x /tmp/convert.sh
sudo /tmp/convert.sh
rm /tmp/convert.sh
```

Although this works well, the shell seems to read the script while cat stores the file and emits some messages. Is there a better way to do this so the shell won't read the script before it runs?

Comment: `sudo sh -c 'some script here'` seems a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The script presented is a wrapper that writes a separate script in `/tmp` and uses the `sudo` command to execute that with elevated privileges.  The reason to do it that way would be to accommodate the possibility that root cannot access the original file, which might be the case if the file resides on a network file system, if mandatory access controls (e.g. SELinux) prevent it, or perhaps for other reasons.

> Is there a better way to do this so the shell won't read the script before it runs?

Of course the shell needs to read the script in order to run it, so I take you to be asking about the creation of an additional script.  That is necessary if you want to accommodate the possibility that root cannot access the original script, though the example implementation is dangerously poor.  If you aren't worried about that possibility then no, it is not necessary to make a separate script.  In that case, one might instead do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $EUID -eq 0 ]] || exec sudo /bin/bash -c "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

some script here
```

That checks whether the script is running with effective user ID 0, and if not, uses `sudo` to relaunch itself.  It does not depend on the original script to be marked executable.  Like the example script, this will be subject to authentication and authorization via `sudo`, which is the only thing that makes the automatic privilege elevation at all reasonable as far as I am concerned.

Comment: I want to add more commands that shouldn't be run as root after the hardcoded script runs. How can it be implemented?

Comment: That would be a different question, @sugkiy.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash I recommend using functions and `declare -f` to transfer properly escaped work to be done.

```
#!/bin/bash

work() {
   some script here
   normally escaped
}

{
   declare -p var1 var2     # transfer variables if any are needed
   declare -f work          # let bash handle the hard escaping
   echo 'work "$@"'         # actually call the 'work' function
} | sudo bash -s            # why create a file? Just forward to shell.
```

Answer (score 0):

John is 100% correct with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69118659/2002471) to this, but I want to note one other possibility for using a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to generate anther script.  There could be variable substitutions in the heredoc.  Even if the same thing could be done somehow without substituting variables during the heredoc stage you should review the code and test it thoroughly to make sure you're not introducing a bug by refactoring out that "oddity".